# $S^2-C$ is locally path connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Show that $S^2-C$, where $C$ is a simple closed curve, is locally path connected.

I am reading the proof of Jordan Separation Theorem in Munkres book. At the very beginning, It states that "Because $S^2-C$ is locally path connected...", without giving any reason. I tried to prove it using the definition of locally path connectedness, but faced difficult in proving so. Is there any theorem that can be used here in order to give that argument? Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That set is homeomorphic to an open subset of the plane, so it is locally homeomorphic to a ball.

Comment: You might like to compare Munkres' proof with that in this paper: http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brouwer-cor-fin.pdf which uses groupoids at one point where Munkres uses covering spaces.  (This paper is a small correction to the account of this area in "Topology and Groupoids", which developed in 1988 from studying Munkres; account.)